# Magento transfer to another server

Tags: magento

We got from our client the ftp files and database sql from a magento website so we can transfer the website to another server. But when I place this in a test modus to see if everything is okay, I get an error saying that a table in the database is already existing. When I delete that table it says that another table is already existing and when I delete that table the previous table is suddenly back. When I delete the whole database and refresh the page it still says that there is a table already existing and when I look back at the database it is back full. What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you please tell me which hosting provider are you using?

Comment: I'm using plesk.

Comment: Have you disabled any activated cache technologies?

Comment: There are no activated cache technologies.

Comment: Well, it seems to be the problem from hosting side because if you have dumped the DB then how come it still stays there? Have you tried any other hosting provider?